# flask file submission returning: root:Files: ImmutableMultiDict([('uploaded_file', <FileStorage: 'file' (None)>)]) and shows up as just 'file'

Tags: python, flask

im creating a microservice mp4 player using docker and when i send a post request with the mp4 file to the file service endpoint, it just shows up at file and i get this
error root:Files: ImmutableMultiDict([('uploaded_file', <FileStorage: 'file' (None)>)])

upload_app.py
this sends the mp4 file to file system

```
import mysql.connector
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'  # Secure secret key

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template_string('''
            <form method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
                Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                Video File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </form>
        ''')

    # Extract credentials from the form
    credentials = {
        'username': request.form.get('username'),
        'password': request.form.get('password')
    }

    # Validate credentials via Authentication Service
    auth_response = requests.post('http://auth-service:5002/validate', json=credentials)
    if auth_response.status_code != 200:
        return "Invalid credentials", 403

    # Mark the user as authenticated for the session
    session['authenticated'] = True

    file = request.files['file']

    # Store file to File System Service
    storage_response = requests.post('http://file-system-service:5003/store', files={'uploaded_file': file})
    if storage_response.status_code != 200:
        return "Error storing file", 500

    filepath = storage_response.text

    # Store filename and path in MySQL
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password', host='mysql-service', database='videos')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO videos (name, path) VALUES (%s, %s)', (file.filename, filepath))
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    return "File uploaded successfully", 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

file_system_app.py
this is supposed to store the file as an mp4 but rather just stores it as file

```
import mysql.connector
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'  # Secure secret key

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template_string('''
            <form method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
                Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                Video File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </form>
        ''')

 
    credentials = {
        'username': request.form.get('username'),
        'password': request.form.get('password')
    }


    auth_response = requests.post('http://auth-service:5002/validate', json=credentials)
    if auth_response.status_code != 200:
        return "Invalid credentials", 403

    session['authenticated'] = True

    file = request.files['file']

    storage_response = requests.post('http://file-system-service:5003/store', files={'uploaded_file': file})
    if storage_response.status_code != 200:
        return "Error storing file", 500

    filepath = storage_response.text


    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='password', host='mysql-service', database='videos')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO videos (name, path) VALUES (%s, %s)', (file.filename, filepath))
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    return "File uploaded successfully", 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

logs:

```
2023-10-10 06:28:57 INFO:werkzeug:Press CTRL+C to quit
2023-10-10 06:29:27 DEBUG:root:Headers: Host: file-system-service:5003
2023-10-10 06:29:27 User-Agent: python-requests/2.25.1
2023-10-10 06:29:27 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2023-10-10 06:29:27 Accept: */*
2023-10-10 06:29:27 Connection: keep-alive
2023-10-10 06:29:27 Content-Length: 3743284
2023-10-10 06:29:27 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=2f34841e464551c61e77920955c68563
2023-10-10 06:29:27 
2023-10-10 06:29:27 
2023-10-10 06:29:27 DEBUG:root:Form: ImmutableMultiDict([])
2023-10-10 06:29:27 DEBUG:root:Files: ImmutableMultiDict([('uploaded_file', <FileStorage: 'file' (None)>)])
2023-10-10 06:29:27 DEBUG:root:Saving file to /app/uploads/file
2023-10-10 06:29:27 DEBUG:root:Original filename: file
2023-10-10 06:29:27 DEBUG:root:File saved successfully to /app/uploads/file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the argument files properly in your post request.

try this code :

```
# your code....

file = request.files['file']
 # check that you have submitted a file
if file.filename != '':
        # Read the file content
        file_contents = uploaded_file.read()

storage_response = requests.post('http://file-systemservice:5003/store',files={'uploaded_file': (file.filename, file_contents)})
if storage_response.status_code != 200:
    return "Error storing file", 500


filepath = storage_response.text

# your code ....
```